# Can MongoDB create friend relationship with one query?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I'm writing some mongoDB queries for Friend relationship. Suppose there is a User document that looks like this:

```
User:
{
    _id: 1
    Friends: [2,3,8] // an array of identifier
}
```

If I want to write queries for two users to become friends, I need to write two queries:

```
  db.Users.update({_id: x}, {$push: {Friends: y}});

  db.Users.update({_id: y}, {$push: {Friends: x}});
```

My question is: can I combine those two above to one query? If yes, how to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't.
Because MongoDB doesn't support such the functionality, you can only write two query to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

afaik you can't do that in a single update but you should be interested in doing bulk updates: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/